# Fiber Product diagram

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

I have the following problem that I can't seem to figure out the trick to. I have the following commutative diagram:

[image]

$X=\{(a,b): a\in A, b\in B$ such that $f(a)=g(b)\}$ is the fiber product, f,g are homomorphisms and $\pi_i$ are regular projections. I have to figure out the following

If $f$ is injective, $\pi_2$ is injective and the same for surjectivity. A hint would be very helpful at least.

Comment: What objects are these? $R$-modules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the description of the fiber product you get: if $\pi_2(a,b)=\pi_2(a',b') $ then $b=b'$. Now suppose $a\neq a'$ then you would get $f(a)=g(b)=f(a')$ a contradiction to the injectivity of $f$.

For surjectivity observe that $f(A)=M$, so for all $b \in B$ you get $g(b)=m=f(a)$ for some suitable $a \in A$. Therefore $\pi_2(a,b)=b$ and so $\pi_2$ is surjective.